# Rotating a needle for a sound level meter

Tags: cocoa-touch, audio, rotation

So i am building a sound level meter app, where i want to rotate a needle in a semi circular speedometer-esque view with regard to the input it is recieving from the microphone. I know the microphone is giving me an output because i can print the results of it in a label and this value changes (between -40 and -90), however my needle is not moving and i don't know why?

Heres my code:

```
-(void) addMeterViewContents
{
UIImage *Needle2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Needle.png"];
UIImageView *Needle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Needle2];
[Needle setFrame:CGRectMake(159, 108, 2, 100)];
self.needleImageView = Needle;
[self.view addSubview:Needle];
angle=([recorder averagePowerForChannel:0])*5000000000;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2]; // Set how long your animation goes for
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
needleImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
needleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(needleImageView.transform, angle *   M_PI/180);

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I looked at the following question:
[How to rotate a needle (for a sound level meter) about it origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226622/how-to-rotate-a-needle-for-a-sound-level-meter-about-it-origin)

But this did not give me an answer.